# Get Equivalent regex in C# for chopping off leading and trailing substring

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

> Javascript :

```
 "[***Smart tag ***]".replace(/^(\[\*\*\*)|(\*\*\*\])$/g, '');
 //  Getting expected output "Smart tag"
```

> In C#.Net

```
 var InputString = "[***Smart tag ***]";  
string Pattern = @"/^(\[\*\*\*)|(\*\*\*\])$/";  
Regex RegexSmarTag = new Regex(Pattern); //Not Working 
var Output = RegexSmarTag.Replace(InputString,""); 
 //Expected out Put : Smart tag //Current outPut : "[***Smart tag ***]";
```

Help me to trim off the characters from the chracters from the input string to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string Pattern = @"^(\[\*\*\*)|(\*\*\*\])$";
```

You don't need `//` delimiters here. You can also rewrite your regex as:

```
string Pattern = @"^(\[\*{3})|(\*{3}\])$";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without the dashes `/` like this

```
string Pattern = @"^(\[\*\*\*)|(\*\*\*\])$";
```